# XQuery vs. XPath 3.1 (in Saxon)

Tags: saxon

We are using Saxon purely to query data. We're about to update to XPath 3.1. For reading queries (no insert/update/delete) is there any difference between XPath 3.1 and XQuery (latest version)?

If so, what? I'm asking to determine if we should implement an XQuery API in our system along with the XPath 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differences are:

- XQuery has node constructors (e.g. `<out>{/x/y}</out>`
- XQuery has full FLWOR expressions with order by, group by, window clauses etc.

So XQuery is a bit more powerful for complex queries, but more importantly, it allows construction of a new XML document to represent the result.